# Converting a list of strings to list of int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

after reading CSV file, I have a column that has a string of comma-separated hexadecimal values. For e.g. "0x00000034,0x0000008a,0x00000145".
I want to convert this column to a list of integers. 
I am able to split and convert to a list of integers using below code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    rnti_list = [int(idx, 16) for idx in row['rnti'].split(",")]
```

I can then add this as a new column.

Wanted to know the most elegant code which would accomplish the same with minimum number of lines.

Thanks.

Comment: Does each "cell" have the same number of hexadecimals, e.g. 3 in your example?

Comment: No. It is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rnti':['0x00000034,0x0000008a,0x00000145','0x00000034,0x0000008a']})
print (df)
                               rnti
0  0x00000034,0x0000008a,0x00000145
1             0x00000034,0x0000008a

rnti_list = [[int(idx, 16) for idx in x.split(",")] for x in df['rnti']]
print (rnti_list)
[[52, 138, 325], [52, 138]]
```

---

```
df['new'] = [[int(idx, 16) for idx in x.split(",")] for x in df['rnti']]
print (df)
                               rnti             new
0  0x00000034,0x0000008a,0x00000145  [52, 138, 325]
1             0x00000034,0x0000008a       [52, 138]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"rnti": ["0x00000034,0x0000008a,0x00000145"]})    
print( df["rnti"].str.split(",").apply(lambda x: [int(i, 16) for i in x]) )
```

**Output:**

```
0    [52, 138, 325]
Name: rnti, dtype: object
```